# php bad control character in string literal, when reading from db

Tags: php, json

I have an associative array with such an element (part of print_r($element)):

```
[przeplywy] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [probes] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => sonda-10

                    )

                [flow] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => created
                                [1] => sip
                                [2] => sport
                                [3] => dip
                                [4] => dport
                                [5] => proto
                                [6] => sensor
                                [7] => os
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2013-09-12 06:10:26
                                [1] => 192.168.0.1
                                [2] => 18560
                                [3] => 10.0.0.1
                                [4] => 1900
                                [5] => UDP
                                [6] => sonda-10
                                [7] => 
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2013-09-12 09:31:08
                                [1] => 192.168.0.1
                                [2] => 13011
                                [3] => 10.0.0.1
                                [4] => 1900
                                [5] => UDP
                                [6] => sonda-10
                                [7] => 
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2013-09-12 09:37:42
                                [1] => 192.168.0.1
                                [2] => 4813
                                [3] => 10.0.0.1
                                [4] => 1900
                                [5] => UDP
                                [6] => sonda-10
                                [7] => 
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2013-09-12 11:24:41
                                [1] => 192.168.0.1
                                [2] => 50091
                                [3] => 10.0.0.1
                                [4] => 1900
                                [5] => UDP
                                [6] => sonda-10
                                [7] => 
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2013-09-12 13:36:55
                                [1] => 192.168.0.1
                                [2] => 17064
                                [3] => 10.0.0.1
                                [4] => 1900
                                [5] => UDP
                                [6] => sonda-10
                                [7] => 
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Iam using json_encode($t['przeplywy']); to save it into MySQL DB as longtext utf8_general_ci. 
In the DB I can see it as :

```
[{"probes":["sonda-10"],"flow":[["created","sip","sport","dip","dport","proto","sensor","os"],["2013-09-12 06:10:26","192.168.0.1","18560","10.0.0.1","1900","UDP","sonda-10",""],["2013-09-12 09:31:08","192.168.0.1","13011","10.0.0.1","1900","UDP","sonda-10",""],["2013-09-12 09:37:42","192.168.0.1","4813","10.0.0.1","1900","UDP","sonda-10",""],["2013-09-12 11:24:41","192.168.0.1","50091","10.0.0.1","1900","UDP","sonda-10",""],["2013-09-12 13:36:55","192.168.0.1","17064","10.0.0.1","1900","UDP","sonda-10",""]]}]
```

when I try to decode it I get null and http://json.parser.online.fr/ claims that is because
"bad control character in string literal" what is wrong?

Comment: seems weird to me to be using `json_encode` to send data between PHP and MySQL - why don't you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or something instead?

Comment: just copied json'ed string to phpfiddle and it decoded fine and return stdCLass object, no errors

Comment: "why don't you use..." I have to write a plugin to an old MantisBT instance that was so badly customized and can't be upgraded... (don't ask me why) I have to use MantisBT DB interface ...

Comment: You can use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) prior to save to DB and [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) after retrieving from DB.

Comment: I mean, use `serialize` **instead** of `json_encode`

Comment: @SergeyRonin In case the programming language changes, JSON can still serve well.

Answer (score -2):

removing control characters from query result did the trick...

```
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '',$row['przeplywy'])
```